# Htaccess - -remove parameters from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need remove a single parameter from url with htaccess

from

```
http://example.com/page/detail/page.php?name=franco&age=50
```

to

```
http://example.com/page/detail/page.php?age=50
```

I am using this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?name=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

But I have this result, I lost the path of page:

```
http://example.com/page.php?eta=57
```

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file located? Your "result" does not match the example URLs you've given? Your code suggests the `name` URL parameter can appear anywhere in the query string, with possibly multiple URL params - however, this is not expressed in your example - can you please confirm. Thanks.

Comment: the file is present into same folder of page. the parameter name is always the first parameter

Comment: See this post "How to remove query strings from URLs" https://helponnet.com/2021/06/07/remove-specific-query-string-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the file is present into same folder of page.

That's the "problem". In per-directory `.htaccess` files the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^/?(.*)$`) matches against the URL-path *less the directory-prefix*, not the full URL-path. In other words, the captured URL-path is simply `page.php`, not `page/detail/page.php` as you are expecting.

Your directives are written as if this `.htaccess` file is in the document root of your site, not in the subdirectory.

Since you are not *changing* the URL-path you can simply use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead in the *substitution* string, which contains the full URL-path (including the slash prefix):

```
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,L]
```

Since you are matching every URL-path, and do not need to capture anything, you can simplify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* from `^/?(.*)$` to `^`. The `%3` backreference in your example is superfluous (you only have 2 captured groups in the preceding *CondPattern*).

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only Change this to a 301 (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid browser caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

The `RewriteCond` regex can also be simplified:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)name=[^&]+&?(.*) [NC]
```

Since the first `&` was optional (ie. `&?`), the preceding subpattern `(.*)` would consume this anyway (which is required). So, the first `&?` can simply be removed. The string anchors `^` and `$` are also not required (regex is *greedy* by default and will consume the entire string regardless).

The `NC` flag is only strictly required if `name` can be mixed case, otherwise, this flag should be removed.

> the parameter name is always the first parameter

If this is so then you don't need the first captured subpattern and can anchor `name=` to the start of the query string. There is now just one backreference (to the string after the `name=<value>` URL parameter).

So, your directives now become:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=[^&]+&?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: but the parameter name is not pass to page.php

Comment: Yes, because the parameter "name" is being _removed_ (with a 3xx redirect). (?)

Comment: is it possible remove only the parameter from url and pass value to page?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense... you can't "remove" it _and_ still pass it. Why are you wanting to "remove" it in the first place, when it is still required by the page?